# Display the product shipping class on Woocommerce single product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to display the shipping class on product page but I must do something wrong because nothing shows..

I used the bellow code in function.php:

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'display_specific_shipping_class', 15 );
function display_specific_shipping_class(){
    global $product;

    // HERE define your targeted shipping class name
    $defined_shipping_class = "Estimated Delivery in 7-15 days";

    $product_shipping_class = $product->get_shipping_class();

    // Get the product shipping class term name
    $term_name = get_term_by( 'slug', $product_shipping_class, 'product_shipping_class' );

    if( $term_name == $defined_shipping_class ){
        echo '<p class="product-shipping-class">' . $term_name . '</p>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the `WP_term` object and not the term name… So instead use the following:

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'display_specific_shipping_class', 15 );
function display_specific_shipping_class(){
    global $product;

    // HERE define your targeted shipping class name
    $defined_shipping_class = "Estimated Delivery in 7-15 days";

    // Get the product shipping class WP_Term Object
    $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $product->get_shipping_class(), 'product_shipping_class' );

    if( is_a($term, 'WP_Term') && $term->name == $defined_shipping_class ){
        echo '<p class="product-shipping-class">' . $term->name . '</p>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works now.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. Iused your code and it's working , but I get this error `PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'name' of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/../../wp-content/themes/..-child/functions.php on line 286`. This is the line with ` if( $term->name == $defined_shipping_class ){`

Comment: With the updated code I get this error `[05-Mar-2019 14:37:19 UTC] PHP Warning:  is_a() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in /var/www/vhosts/..../.../wp-content/themes/...-child/functions.php on line 286`

Comment: @Helen_zs Updated: Sorry I have inverted the arguments in `is_a()` conditional function. Try it again, it should work now.